# Text of link will only show if my mouse hovers over link area, not anywhere in whole button

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I don't know if I'll successfully convey what I mean but here goes. I have some CSS and am trying to get the text label of a link in a navigation to button to show if I hover anywhere over that button, not just over where the link should display. What happens is when I hover over most of the button, the button goes all-white. I want it to be white background, but show the text. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Just try something as below:

    CSS:


    .CSSButton {
border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.1, #FFFFFF), color-stop(0.9, #D1D1D1) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #FFFFFF 10%, #D1D1D1 90% );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#D1D1D1');
background-color: #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 0px #FFFFFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px  2px 0px #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px  2px 0px #FFFFFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px 5px;
padding: 6px 6px;
color: #999999;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
width: 150px;
text-transform: capitalize;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}
.CSSButton:hover {
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.1, #D1D1D1), color-stop(0.9, #FFFFFF) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #D1D1D1 10%, #FFFFFF 90% );
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#D1D1D1', endColorstr='#FFFFFF');
background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.CSSButton:active {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
left: 0px;
}




    HTML:

    <span class="CSSButton">Click Me!</span>
```